# What does a period RDATE mean?

Tags: icalendar, rfc5545

RFC 5545 allows the RDATE property to have a data type of PERIOD. What are the semantics of this data type? As far as I can tell, it's unspecified. Does it change the duration of the event? What if it's on a time zone change, which can't have a duration?

Answer (score 2):

Though I agree with you that RFC5545 leaves too many things for interpretation, in this occasion it seems to be giving some guidance for combinationss of `PERIOD` and `RDATE`:

> For example, recurrence instances of a nominal
>         duration of one day will have an exact duration of more or less
>         than 24 hours on a day where a time zone shift occurs.  The
>         duration of a specific recurrence may be modified in an exception
>         component or simply by using an "RDATE" property of PERIOD value
>         type.

and

> When the combination of the "RRULE" and "RDATE" properties in a
>          recurring component produces multiple instances having the same
>          start DATE-TIME value, they should be collapsed to, and
>          considered as, a single instance.  If the "RDATE" property is
>          specified as a PERIOD value the duration of the recurrence
>          instance will be the one specified by the "RDATE" property, and
>          not the duration of the recurrence instance defined by the
>          "DTSTART" property.

and example is available:

```
RDATE;VALUE=PERIOD:19960403T020000Z/19960403T040000Z,
    19960404T010000Z/PT3H
```